# Jmeter JSR223 Method addOptions( com.jayway.jsonpath.Option ) not found in class'com.jayway.jsonpath.Configuration

Tags: jmeter, jsonpath, jsr223

I'm getting error while running the bellow java code in Jmeter JSR223 sampler

```
import com.jayway.jsonpath.Configuration;
import com.jayway.jsonpath.JsonPath;
import com.jayway.jsonpath.Option;
import net.minidev.json.JSONArray;


String json = "{\"store\":{\"book\":[{\"category\":\"reference\",\"author\":\"Nigel Rees\",\"title\":\"Sayings of the Century\",\"price\":8.95},{\"category\":\"fiction\",\"author\":\"Evelyn Waugh\",\"title\":\"Sword of Honour\",\"price\":12.99},{\"category\":\"fiction\",\"author\":\"Herman Melville\",\"title\":\"Moby Dick\",\"isbn\":\"0-553-21311-3\",\"price\":8.99},{\"category\":\"fiction\",\"author\":\"J. R. R. Tolkien\",\"title\":\"The Lord of the Rings\",\"isbn\":\"0-395-19395-8\",\"price\":22.99}],\"bicycle\":{\"color\":\"red\",\"price\":19.95}},\"expensive\":10}";

        String jsonPath = "$..book[?(@.author == 'Nigel Rees')].title";

        Configuration config = Configuration.defaultConfiguration().addOptions(Option.DEFAULT_PATH_LEAF_TO_NULL);

        JSONArray authorsArr = JsonPath.using(config).parse(json).read(jsonPath);

        System.out.println(authorsArr.get(0).toString());
```

json-path-2.4.0.jar is added under ..\lib\ext and assume it is automatically loaded on Jmeter start.

The above code is checked in IDE and is running fine.

JSR223 Error

```
2021-02-02 17:19:10,580 ERROR o.a.j.p.j.s.JSR223Sampler: Problem in JSR223 script JSR223 Sampler, message: javax.script.ScriptException: Sourced file: inline evaluation of: ``import com.jayway.jsonpath.Configuration; import com.jayway.jsonpath.JsonPath; i . . . '' : Typed variable declaration : Error in method invocation: Method addOptions( com.jayway.jsonpath.Option ) not found in class'com.jayway.jsonpath.Configuration' : at Line: 11 : in file: inline evaluation of: ``import com.jayway.jsonpath.Configuration; import com.jayway.jsonpath.JsonPath; i . . . '' : .addOptions ( Option .DEFAULT_PATH_LEAF_TO_NULL ) 
 in inline evaluation of: ``import com.jayway.jsonpath.Configuration; import com.jayway.jsonpath.JsonPath; i . . . '' at line number 11
javax.script.ScriptException: Sourced file: inline evaluation of: ``import com.jayway.jsonpath.Configuration; import com.jayway.jsonpath.JsonPath; i . . . '' : Typed variable declaration : Error in method invocation: Method addOptions( com.jayway.jsonpath.Option ) not found in class'com.jayway.jsonpath.Configuration' : at Line: 11 : in file: inline evaluation of: ``import com.jayway.jsonpath.Configuration; import com.jayway.jsonpath.JsonPath; i . . . '' : .addOptions ( Option .DEFAULT_PATH_LEAF_TO_NULL ) 
 in inline evaluation of: ``import com.jayway.jsonpath.Configuration; import com.jayway.jsonpath.JsonPath; i . . . '' at line number 11
    at bsh.engine.BshScriptEngine.evalSource(BshScriptEngine.java:93) ~[bsh-2.0b6.jar:2.0b6 2016-02-05 05:16:19]
    at bsh.engine.BshScriptEngine.eval(BshScriptEngine.java:46) ~[bsh-2.0b6.jar:2.0b6 2016-02-05 05:16:19]
    at javax.script.AbstractScriptEngine.eval(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_241]
    at org.apache.jmeter.util.JSR223TestElement.processFileOrScript(JSR223TestElement.java:223) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:4.0 r1823414]
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.java.sampler.JSR223Sampler.sample(JSR223Sampler.java:69) [ApacheJMeter_java.jar:4.0 r1823414]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.executeSamplePackage(JMeterThread.java:490) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:4.0 r1823414]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.processSampler(JMeterThread.java:416) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:4.0 r1823414]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:250) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:4.0 r1823414]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_241]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Change "Language" to `groovy`, if you choose `java` it isn't really Java, it's [Beanshell](http://beanshell.org/) which

   - is not fully Java-compliant
   - has much worse performance comparing to Groovy

   So [according to JMeter Best Practices you should switch to Groovy since JMeter 3.1](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting). More information: [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)
2. Change this line:

   ```
   String jsonPath = "$..book[?(@.author == 'Nigel Rees')].title";
   ```

   to this one

   ```
   String jsonPath = '$..book[?(@.author == \'Nigel Rees\')].title'
   ```

   as your Java syntax slightly conflicts with Groovy [GString Template Engine](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/next/html/documentation/template-engines.html#_gstringtemplateengine)
3. You should not require any extra .jars, the code will work on vanilla JMeter instance

   [image]

Also be aware that Groovy has [built-in JSON support](https://groovy-lang.org/json.html)